# Skip fitting the final model with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

Sometimes when I fit a model with caret, I am really just interested to see how it performs using the resampling method I have chosen (e.g. cross-validation).

When I am not interested in the "final model" built on the full training data, I would like to avoid fitting it. It is really just about saving precious minutes multiple times during development.

Is there any way to skip fitting the final model when using caret? I have not seen any relevant arguments in `caret::trainControl` or `caret::train`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There indeed doesn't seem to be an argument that directly achieves that. There are a couple of candidate solutions, though.

1. `selectionFunction` as an argument of `trainControl` selects the final model based on candidate models' performance (with there being only one candidate when there is no parameter tuning) in terms of accuracy, RMSE, etc. Setting `selectionFunction` as something like `function(x, ...) NA` or `function(x, ...) NULL` fails. However, something like `function(x, ...) -1` does partially work: there is no warning or error returned, and a final model is *attempted* to fit. The final outcome seems to be model-dependent.
2. Another argument of `trainControl` of interest is `indexFinal`:

   > an optional vector of integers indicating which samples are used to
   >   fit the final model after resampling. If NULL, then entire data set is
   >   used.

   Setting it to `NA` appears to fail with most models, except kNN. Setting it to something like `1:10` fit a final model, *if there are few enough parameters*, using only those ten observations. Hence, setting it to something like `1:100` should work in many cases and take little time.
3. You may of course alter the `train` function itself. In the following I only add an argument `fitFinal`, which is `TRUE` by default, and check if it's `TRUE` when going to fit the final model. If `fitFinal == FALSE`, then

   ```
   finalModel <- list(fit = NULL, preProc = NULL)
   finalTime <- 0
   ```

   Everything else seems to run smoothly. As to overwrite the actual `train.default` function, you should afterwards run

   ```
   environment(myTrain) <- environment(caret:::train.default)
   assignInNamespace("train.default", myTrain, ns = "caret")
   ```

   So, we have

   ```
   myTrain <- function (x, y, method = "rf", preProcess = NULL, ..., weights = NULL, fitFinal = TRUE,
                        metric = ifelse(is.factor(y), "Accuracy", "RMSE"), maximize = ifelse(metric %in%
                                                                                               c("RMSE", "logLoss", "MAE"), FALSE, TRUE), trControl = trainControl(),
                        tuneGrid = NULL, tuneLength = ifelse(trControl$method ==
                                                               "none", 1, 3))
   {
     startTime <- proc.time()
     rs_seed <- sample.int(.Machine$integer.max, 1L)
     if (is.null(colnames(x)))
       stop("Please use column names for `x`", call. = FALSE)
     if (is.character(y))
       y <- as.factor(y)
     if (!is.numeric(y) & !is.factor(y)) {
       stop("Please make sure `y` is a factor or numeric value.",
            call. = FALSE)
     }
     if (is.list(method)) {
       minNames <- c("library", "type", "parameters", "grid",
                     "fit", "predict", "prob")
       nameCheck <- minNames %in% names(method)
       if (!all(nameCheck))
         stop(paste("some required components are missing:",
                    paste(minNames[!nameCheck], collapse = ", ")),
              call. = FALSE)
       models <- method
       method <- "custom"
     }
     else {
       models <- getModelInfo(method, regex = FALSE)[[1]]
       if (length(models) == 0)
         stop(paste("Model", method, "is not in caret's built-in library"),
              call. = FALSE)
     }
     checkInstall(models$library)
     for (i in seq(along = models$library)) do.call("requireNamespaceQuietStop",
                                                    list(package = models$library[i]))
     if (any(names(models) == "check") && is.function(models$check)) {
       software_check <- models$check(models$library)
     }
     paramNames <- as.character(models$parameters$parameter)
     funcCall <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
     modelType <- get_model_type(y)
     if (!(modelType %in% models$type))
       stop(paste("wrong model type for", tolower(modelType)),
            call. = FALSE)
     if (grepl("^svm", method) & grepl("String$", method)) {
       if (is.vector(x) && is.character(x)) {
         stop("'x' should be a character matrix with a single column for string kernel methods",
              call. = FALSE)
       }
       if (is.matrix(x) && is.numeric(x)) {
         stop("'x' should be a character matrix with a single column for string kernel methods",
              call. = FALSE)
       }
       if (is.data.frame(x)) {
         stop("'x' should be a character matrix with a single column for string kernel methods",
              call. = FALSE)
       }
     }
     if (modelType == "Regression" & length(unique(y)) == 2)
       warning(paste("You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has",
                     "two possible values Are you trying to do classification?",
                     "If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column."))
     if (modelType != "Classification" & !is.null(trControl$sampling))
       stop("sampling methods are only implemented for classification problems",
            call. = FALSE)
     if (!is.null(trControl$sampling)) {
       trControl$sampling <- parse_sampling(trControl$sampling)
     }
     if (any(class(x) == "data.table"))
       x <- as.data.frame(x)
     check_dims(x = x, y = y)
     n <- if (class(y)[1] == "Surv")
       nrow(y)
     else length(y)
     parallel_check("RWeka", models)
     parallel_check("keras", models)
     if (!is.null(preProcess) && !(all(names(preProcess) %in%
                                       ppMethods)))
       stop(paste("pre-processing methods are limited to:",
                  paste(ppMethods, collapse = ", ")), call. = FALSE)
     if (modelType == "Classification") {
       classLevels <- levels(y)
       attributes(classLevels) <- list(ordered = is.ordered(y))
       xtab <- table(y)
       if (any(xtab == 0)) {
         xtab_msg <- paste("'", names(xtab)[xtab == 0], "'",
                           collapse = ", ", sep = "")
         stop(paste("One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data:",
                    xtab_msg), call. = FALSE)
       }
       if (trControl$classProbs && any(classLevels != make.names(classLevels))) {
         stop(paste("At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name;",
                    "This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because",
                    "the variables names will be converted to ",
                    paste(make.names(classLevels), collapse = ", "),
                    ". Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names",
                    " (see ?make.names for help)."), call. = FALSE)
       }
       if (metric %in% c("RMSE", "Rsquared"))
         stop(paste("Metric", metric, "not applicable for classification models"),
              call. = FALSE)
       if (!trControl$classProbs && metric == "ROC")
         stop(paste("Class probabilities are needed to score models using the",
                    "area under the ROC curve. Set `classProbs = TRUE`",
                    "in the trainControl() function."), call. = FALSE)
       if (trControl$classProbs) {
         if (!is.function(models$prob)) {
           warning("Class probabilities were requested for a model that does not implement them")
           trControl$classProbs <- FALSE
         }
       }
     }
     else {
       if (metric %in% c("Accuracy", "Kappa"))
         stop(paste("Metric", metric, "not applicable for regression models"),
              call. = FALSE)
       classLevels <- NA
       if (trControl$classProbs) {
         warning("cannnot compute class probabilities for regression")
         trControl$classProbs <- FALSE
       }
     }
     if (trControl$method == "oob" & is.null(models$oob))
       stop("Out of bag estimates are not implemented for this model",
            call. = FALSE)
     trControl <- withr::with_seed(rs_seed, make_resamples(trControl,
                                                           outcome = y))
     if (is.logical(trControl$savePredictions)) {
       trControl$savePredictions <- if (trControl$savePredictions)
         "all"
       else "none"
     }
     else {
       if (!(trControl$savePredictions %in% c("all", "final",
                                              "none")))
         stop("`savePredictions` should be either logical or \"all\", \"final\" or \"none\"",
              call. = FALSE)
     }
     if (!is.null(preProcess)) {
       ppOpt <- list(options = preProcess)
       if (length(trControl$preProcOptions) > 0)
         ppOpt <- c(ppOpt, trControl$preProcOptions)
     }
     else ppOpt <- NULL
     if (is.null(tuneGrid)) {
       if (!is.null(ppOpt) && length(models$parameters$parameter) >
           1 && as.character(models$parameters$parameter) !=
           "parameter") {
         pp <- list(method = ppOpt$options)
         if ("ica" %in% pp$method)
           pp$n.comp <- ppOpt$ICAcomp
         if ("pca" %in% pp$method)
           pp$thresh <- ppOpt$thresh
         if ("knnImpute" %in% pp$method)
           pp$k <- ppOpt$k
         pp$x <- x
         ppObj <- do.call("preProcess", pp)
         tuneGrid <- models$grid(x = predict(ppObj, x), y = y,
                                 len = tuneLength, search = trControl$search)
         rm(ppObj, pp)
       }
       else {
         tuneGrid <- models$grid(x = x, y = y, len = tuneLength,
                                 search = trControl$search)
         if (trControl$search != "grid" && tuneLength < nrow(tuneGrid))
           tuneGrid <- tuneGrid[1:tuneLength, , drop = FALSE]
       }
     }
     if (grepl("adaptive", trControl$method) & nrow(tuneGrid) ==
         1) {
       stop(paste("For adaptive resampling, there needs to be more than one",
                  "tuning parameter for evaluation"), call. = FALSE)
     }
     dotNames <- hasDots(tuneGrid, models)
     if (dotNames)
       colnames(tuneGrid) <- gsub("^\\.", "", colnames(tuneGrid))
     tuneNames <- as.character(models$parameters$parameter)
     goodNames <- all.equal(sort(tuneNames), sort(names(tuneGrid)))
     if (!is.logical(goodNames) || !goodNames) {
       stop(paste("The tuning parameter grid should have columns",
                  paste(tuneNames, collapse = ", ", sep = "")), call. = FALSE)
     }
     if (trControl$method == "none" && nrow(tuneGrid) != 1)
       stop("Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling",
            call. = FALSE)
     trControl$yLimits <- if (is.numeric(y))
       get_range(y)
     else NULL
     if (trControl$method != "none") {
       if (is.function(models$loop) && nrow(tuneGrid) > 1) {
         trainInfo <- models$loop(tuneGrid)
         if (!all(c("loop", "submodels") %in% names(trainInfo)))
           stop("The 'loop' function should produce a list with elements 'loop' and 'submodels'",
                call. = FALSE)
         lengths <- unlist(lapply(trainInfo$submodels, nrow))
         if (all(lengths == 0))
           trainInfo$submodels <- NULL
       }
       else trainInfo <- list(loop = tuneGrid)
       num_rs <- if (trControl$method != "oob")
         length(trControl$index)
       else 1L
       if (trControl$method %in% c("boot632", "optimism_boot",
                                   "boot_all"))
         num_rs <- num_rs + 1L
       if (is.null(trControl$seeds) || all(is.na(trControl$seeds))) {
         seeds <- sample.int(n = 1000000L, size = num_rs *
                               nrow(trainInfo$loop) + 1L)
         seeds <- lapply(seq(from = 1L, to = length(seeds),
                             by = nrow(trainInfo$loop)), function(x) {
                               seeds[x:(x + nrow(trainInfo$loop) - 1L)]
                             })
         seeds[[num_rs + 1L]] <- seeds[[num_rs + 1L]][1L]
         trControl$seeds <- seeds
       }
       else {
         if (!(length(trControl$seeds) == 1 && is.na(trControl$seeds))) {
           numSeeds <- unlist(lapply(trControl$seeds, length))
           badSeed <- (length(trControl$seeds) < num_rs +
                         1L) || (any(numSeeds[-length(numSeeds)] < nrow(trainInfo$loop))) ||
             (numSeeds[length(numSeeds)] < 1L)
           if (badSeed)
             stop(paste("Bad seeds: the seed object should be a list of length",
                        num_rs + 1, "with", num_rs, "integer vectors of size",
                        nrow(trainInfo$loop), "and the last list element having at least a",
                        "single integer"), call. = FALSE)
           if (any(is.na(unlist(trControl$seeds))))
             stop("At least one seed is missing (NA)", call. = FALSE)
         }
       }
       if (trControl$method == "oob") {
         perfNames <- metric
       }
       else {
         testSummary <- evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights,
                                            ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, metric = metric,
                                            method = method)
         perfNames <- names(testSummary)
       }
       if (!(metric %in% perfNames)) {
         oldMetric <- metric
         metric <- perfNames[1]
         warning(paste("The metric \"", oldMetric, "\" was not in ",
                       "the result set. ", metric, " will be used instead.",
                       sep = ""))
       }
       if (trControl$method == "oob") {
         tmp <- oobTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights,
                                 info = trainInfo, method = models, ppOpts = preProcess,
                                 ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, ...)
         performance <- tmp
         perfNames <- colnames(performance)
         perfNames <- perfNames[!(perfNames %in% as.character(models$parameters$parameter))]
         if (!(metric %in% perfNames)) {
           oldMetric <- metric
           metric <- perfNames[1]
           warning(paste("The metric \"", oldMetric, "\" was not in ",
                         "the result set. ", metric, " will be used instead.",
                         sep = ""))
         }
       }
       else {
         if (trControl$method == "LOOCV") {
           tmp <- looTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights,
                                   info = trainInfo, method = models, ppOpts = preProcess,
                                   ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, ...)
           performance <- tmp$performance
         }
         else {
           if (!grepl("adapt", trControl$method)) {
             tmp <- nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights,
                                         info = trainInfo, method = models, ppOpts = preProcess,
                                         ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, ...)
             performance <- tmp$performance
             resampleResults <- tmp$resample
           }
           else {
             tmp <- adaptiveWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights,
                                     info = trainInfo, method = models, ppOpts = preProcess,
                                     ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, metric = metric,
                                     maximize = maximize, ...)
             performance <- tmp$performance
             resampleResults <- tmp$resample
           }
         }
       }
       trControl$indexExtra <- NULL
       if (!(trControl$method %in% c("LOOCV", "oob"))) {
         if (modelType == "Classification" && length(grep("^\\cell",
                                                          colnames(resampleResults))) > 0) {
           resampledCM <- resampleResults[, !(names(resampleResults) %in%
                                                perfNames)]
           resampleResults <- resampleResults[, -grep("^\\cell",
                                                      colnames(resampleResults))]
         }
         else resampledCM <- NULL
       }
       else resampledCM <- NULL
       if (trControl$verboseIter) {
         cat("Aggregating results\n")
         flush.console()
       }
       perfCols <- names(performance)
       perfCols <- perfCols[!(perfCols %in% paramNames)]
       if (all(is.na(performance[, metric]))) {
         cat(paste("Something is wrong; all the", metric,
                   "metric values are missing:\n"))
         print(summary(performance[, perfCols[!grepl("SD$",
                                                     perfCols)], drop = FALSE]))
         stop("Stopping", call. = FALSE)
       }
       if (!is.null(models$sort))
         performance <- models$sort(performance)
       if (any(is.na(performance[, metric])))
         warning("missing values found in aggregated results")
       if (trControl$verboseIter && nrow(performance) > 1) {
         cat("Selecting tuning parameters\n")
         flush.console()
       }
       selectClass <- class(trControl$selectionFunction)[1]
       if (grepl("adapt", trControl$method)) {
         perf_check <- subset(performance, .B == max(performance$.B))
       }
       else perf_check <- performance
       if (selectClass == "function") {
         bestIter <- trControl$selectionFunction(x = perf_check,
                                                 metric = metric, maximize = maximize)
       }
       else {
         if (trControl$selectionFunction == "oneSE") {
           bestIter <- oneSE(perf_check, metric, length(trControl$index),
                             maximize)
         }
         else {
           bestIter <- do.call(trControl$selectionFunction,
                               list(x = perf_check, metric = metric, maximize = maximize))
         }
       }
       if (is.na(bestIter) || length(bestIter) != 1)
         stop("final tuning parameters could not be determined",
              call. = FALSE)
       if (grepl("adapt", trControl$method)) {
         best_perf <- perf_check[bestIter, as.character(models$parameters$parameter),
                                 drop = FALSE]
         performance$order <- 1:nrow(performance)
         bestIter <- merge(performance, best_perf)$order
         performance$order <- NULL
       }
       bestTune <- performance[bestIter, paramNames, drop = FALSE]
     }
     else {
       bestTune <- tuneGrid
       performance <- evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights,
                                          ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, metric = metric,
                                          method = method)
       perfNames <- names(performance)
       performance <- as.data.frame(t(performance))
       performance <- cbind(performance, tuneGrid)
       performance <- performance[-1, , drop = FALSE]
       tmp <- resampledCM <- NULL
     }
     if (!(trControl$method %in% c("LOOCV", "oob", "none"))) {
       byResample <- switch(trControl$returnResamp, none = NULL,
                            all = {
                              out <- resampleResults
                              colnames(out) <- gsub("^\\.", "", colnames(out))
                              out
                            }, final = {
                              out <- merge(bestTune, resampleResults)
                              out <- out[, !(names(out) %in% names(tuneGrid)),
                                         drop = FALSE]
                              out
                            })
     }
     else {
       byResample <- NULL
     }
     orderList <- list()
     for (i in seq(along = paramNames)) orderList[[i]] <- performance[,
                                                                      paramNames[i]]
     performance <- performance[do.call("order", orderList), ]
     if (trControl$verboseIter) {
       bestText <- paste(paste(names(bestTune), "=", format(bestTune,
                                                            digits = 3)), collapse = ", ")
       if (nrow(performance) == 1)
         bestText <- "final model"
       cat("Fitting", bestText, "on full training set\n")
       flush.console()
     }
     indexFinal <- if (is.null(trControl$indexFinal))
       seq(along = y)
     else trControl$indexFinal
     if (!(length(trControl$seeds) == 1 && is.na(trControl$seeds)))
       set.seed(trControl$seeds[[length(trControl$seeds)]][1])
     if (fitFinal) {
       finalTime <- system.time(finalModel <- createModel(x = subset_x(x,
                                                                       indexFinal), y = y[indexFinal], wts = weights[indexFinal],
                                                          method = models, tuneValue = bestTune, obsLevels = classLevels,
                                                          pp = ppOpt, last = TRUE, classProbs = trControl$classProbs,
                                                          sampling = trControl$sampling, ...))
     } else {
       finalModel <- list(fit = NULL, preProc = NULL)
       finalTime <- 0
     }
     if (trControl$trim && !is.null(models$trim)) {
       if (trControl$verboseIter)
         old_size <- object.size(finalModel$fit)
       finalModel$fit <- models$trim(finalModel$fit)
       if (trControl$verboseIter) {
         new_size <- object.size(finalModel$fit)
         reduction <- format(old_size - new_size, units = "Mb")
         if (reduction == "0 Mb")
           reduction <- "< 0 Mb"
         p_reduction <- (unclass(old_size) - unclass(new_size))/unclass(old_size) *
           100
         p_reduction <- if (p_reduction < 1)
           "< 1%"
         else paste0(round(p_reduction, 0), "%")
         cat("Final model footprint reduced by", reduction,
             "or", p_reduction, "\n")
       }
     }
     pp <- finalModel$preProc
     finalModel <- finalModel$fit
     if (method == "pls")
       finalModel$bestIter <- bestTune
     if (method == "glmnet")
       finalModel$lambdaOpt <- bestTune$lambda
     if (trControl$returnData) {
       outData <- if (!is.data.frame(x))
         try(as.data.frame(x), silent = TRUE)
       else x
       if (inherits(outData, "try-error")) {
         warning("The training data could not be converted to a data frame for saving")
         outData <- NULL
       }
       else {
         outData$.outcome <- y
         if (!is.null(weights))
           outData$.weights <- weights
       }
     }
     else outData <- NULL
     if (trControl$savePredictions == "final")
       tmp$predictions <- merge(bestTune, tmp$predictions)
     endTime <- proc.time()
     times <- list(everything = endTime - startTime, final = finalTime)
     out <- structure(list(method = method, modelInfo = models,
                           modelType = modelType, results = performance, pred = tmp$predictions,
                           bestTune = bestTune, call = funcCall, dots = list(...),
                           metric = metric, control = trControl, finalModel = finalModel,
                           preProcess = pp, trainingData = outData, resample = byResample,
                           resampledCM = resampledCM, perfNames = perfNames, maximize = maximize,
                           yLimits = trControl$yLimits, times = times, levels = classLevels),
                      class = "train")
     trControl$yLimits <- NULL
     if (trControl$timingSamps > 0) {
       pData <- x[sample(1:nrow(x), trControl$timingSamps, replace = TRUE),
                  , drop = FALSE]
       out$times$prediction <- system.time(predict(out, pData))
     }
     else out$times$prediction <- rep(NA, 3)
     out
   }
   ```

   That gives

   ```
   data(iris)
   TrainData <- iris[,1:4]
   TrainClasses <- iris[,5]

   knnFit1 <- train(TrainData, TrainClasses,
                    method = "knn",
                    preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                    tuneLength = 10,
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"), fitFinal = FALSE)
   knnFit1$finalModel
   # NULL
   ```

Comment: how about `indexFinal = NA`

Comment: @missuse, right! Didn't expect that to work, just like with `selectionFunction`.

Comment: Setting the index to NA  is not a go-to solution as it does not always work - you should remove it from your answer. For example it fails with a simple `lm` : `train(Sepal.Length ~ .,
                 data=iris,
                 method = "lm",
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", indexFinal = NA))`. I'll use `indexFinal=1` for now but I was rather hoping to disable the fitting completely. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, using `NA` causes a failure for all the (10+) models I have just tried except knn... I guess you were unlucky!

Comment: @antoine-sac, interesting. I updated the answer. Note that `indexFinal = 1` doesn't seem to always work either; I just tried to use SVM even with `1:50` and it still wasn't enough.

Comment: @antoine-sac, added another option.